# tf.train.get_checkpoint_state always None

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tf.train.get_checkpoint_state to check whether I have a valid checkpoint file to restore a Tensorflow saved model.

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('fi/saves'))
if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
   saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

My issue is that ckpt is always None. Here is the content of my saves directory:

- internals.pkl
- stats.json
- variables.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- variables.ckpt.index

Please note that a call to restore directly works well.

**EDIT:**

I have tried using the latest_filename argument like this:

```
tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname(checkpoint_dir), latest_filename='variables.ckpt.index')
```

I am still getting None.

Comment: Have you tried passing `latest_filename` set to the name of your file?

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes, I did. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that tf.train.get_checkpoint_state looks for a checkpoint file.

I did not have this file because I was doing this when saving:

```
saver.save(sess, variables_file_path, write_meta_graph=False, write_state=False)
```

Instead of:

```
saver.save(sess, variables_file_path, write_meta_graph=False, write_state=True)  # write state is true by default.
```

This now works !